# Keeping tick marks attached to my axis in R ggplot2 when zooming

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I would like to export this graph from RStudio on a larger resolution but when I do this the tick marks of the x-axis separate from the axis.
I have looked at documentation for theme() but did not find a relevant function: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html

So how can I keep my ticks connected to the x-axis?
I tried using the space between ticks and axis labels but it just changes the relevant spacing, but does not change the spacing I am talking about.

Code to generate the images I depicted below:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)

setsTimeline <- data.table(Set=c("Training Set","Validation Set","Test Set","Training Set","Validation Set","Test Set","Training Set","Validation Set","Test Set","Training Set","Validation Set","Test Set","Training Set"),
       StartDate=c(1380708900,1402963200,1420070400,1421280000,1410912000,1396310400,1397520000,1418860800,1404172800,1405382400,1395100800,1412121600,1413331200),
       EndDate=  c(1395099900,1404171900,1421279100,1430985600,1412120700,1397519100,1402962300,1420069500,1405381500,1410911100,1396309500,1413330300,1418859900))

setsTimeline[,StartLabel:=as.POSIXct(StartDate,tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")]
setkey(setsTimeline,StartDate)

breaks <- c(1380708900,1395100800,1402963200,1410912000,1418860800,1430985600)
labels <- as.POSIXct(breaks,tz="UTC",origin="1970-01-01")

ggplot(setsTimeline, aes(colour=Set)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=StartDate, xend=EndDate, y="group", yend="group"), size=10) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    aspect.ratio=5e-02, 
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour='black', angle = 45, size = 16, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(colour='black', size = 16),
    legend.title = element_text(colour='black', size = 0),
    legend.position = 'top',
    plot.title = element_text(colour='black', size = 18),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,0,3.5), "cm")) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL) +
  ggtitle(NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1380708900,1430985600), ylim = NULL) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks,labels=labels)
```

Small res:
[image: No spacing between axis and ticks]

High res:
[image: Suddenly spacing between axis and ticks :o]

Comment: Can you edit your question so it contains the code you used to make the graph?

Comment: How do you export images? By using the "Export" button in RStudio?

Comment: I'm using Rstudio but I don't think the exporting part is the issue here as the problem already shows when you press the zoom button for the plot in RStudio.
As the export image often does not work I usually copy the image and paste it in Paint actually :p